# Can't login to MySQL with Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtualbox

Background: I am on a Windows 7 host, with Virtual Box, and Vagrant. I installed an Ubuntu guest - ubuntu/precise64, and then Apache, MySQL and PHP. I set the MySQL password, and ran through mysql_secure_installation.
My problem is this: When I am logged in via SSH to my server (as root), I cannot seem to connect to MySQL. Running `mysql -u root -p`
and then entering my MySQL password gets this notice:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

On the other hand, if I do this: `mysql -u root --password=*my-mysql-root-password*` I get in. Why is this happening?

Comment: change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Where do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found the answer. The problem was that my mysql root password was longer than 8 characters. Changing the password to less than 8 characters solved the issue. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html:

> On some systems, the library routine that MySQL uses to prompt for a password automatically limits the password to eight characters. That is a problem with the system library, not with MySQL. Internally, MySQL does not have any limit for the length of the password. To work around the problem, change your MySQL password to a value that is eight or fewer characters long, or put your password in an option file.